How to efficiently find common elements between two large lists in Python while maintaining order?
I am working with two large lists of integers in Python, and I need to find the common elements between them. The result should preserve the order of the elements as they appear in the first list and must not contain duplicates. For example:
I've tried using a nested loop, but the performance is very slow with large lists. I want to optimize the solution for time complexity. What would be the best approach to achieve this in Python?

You could convert them to to sets and use the bitwise operator/logical(&) to effectively combine to 2 lists and meet your criteria.
def find_common_elements(list1 :list, list2:list):
    set1 = set(list1)
    set2 = set(list2)
    
    return list(set1 & set2)


Use a set to store elements from the second list, which allows for O(1) average-time complexity for membership checks.
Use a second set to keep track of elements already added to the result to avoid duplicates.
Iterate over the first list and check if the element is in the second list's set and has not already been added to the result.
def find_common_elements(list1, list2):
    set_list2 = set(list2)  
    seen = set()           
    result = []
    for elem in list1:
        if elem in set_list2 and elem not in seen:
            result.append(elem)
            seen.add(elem)
    return result
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [3, 6, 9, 12]
result = find_common_elements(list1, list2)
print(result)  

